# Error in calling crypto prices in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, cryptocurrency

This command:

```
=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTDATA("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD"), "{.+:(.+)}"))
```

used to work just fine for ETH and BTC, but it is giving me this error now:

> Error
>   Function `REGEXEXTRACT` parameter 2 value `"{.+:(.+)}"` does not match text of 
> Function `REGEXEXTRACT` parameter 1 value `"{"Response":"Error""`.

What's the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptoprices.cc/BTC/")`

There's no parsing required, no limitations, no authentication.

Answer (score 0):

try it perhaps tomorrow (you probably reached the max limit of free API calls for the day)

[image]

Comment: Lol thanks, you may be right because today it has started working again!

Comment: Ok, I just found out that it is still giving me the same darn error in another sheet. So to summarize, today is tomorrow, and one of my sheets is OK with no error, the other one keeps giving me the same error Yesterday they both had the same error.

Comment: try tomorrow perhaps :) these free api calls limits are very easy to reach. some of them are bound to reload too so they could last even just a few moments. I see you are after ETHtoUSD... check these alternatives: https://medium.com/cryptofinance-ai/how-to-get-bitcoin-and-other-cryptocurrency-prices-in-your-spreadsheet-for-free-4f6d59d1a2fd (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125495/186471)

Comment: I had the cryptofinance add on before, and I removed it because it reached the limit quickly as you suggested. Now I have placed the api call using Kraken exchange and it took a while to work, but I used it in one of my spreadsheets, and it seems to be fine. Only time will tell I guess. How do I select your second answer as the best answer?